# Nodejs - writing JSON Object into a properties file

Tags: json, node.js, properties

I have a JSON Object as follows

{ "A":1, "B":2, "C":3 }

How to write the JSON into a properties file which has following format using node js

## file contents

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
```

I have tried this way

I tried this was

## app.js

```
app.post('/writeprop', function (req, res) {
    logger.log('info', 'Write Properties : ' + "args" + req.body.propObj);
    fileHandler.writeProperties( req.body.propObj, function (error, values){
        logger.log('info', "Writing Properties.. ");
        if (error == null) {
          res.send(values);
        }
        else {
          logger.log('info', error);
        }
    });
});
```

## filehandler.js

```
function writeProperties(pptObj, callback){
        properties.stringify (pptObj, { path: basePath + 'test.properties' }, function (error, obj){
            if (error){
                callback(error, null);
                return console.error (error);
            } else {
                console.log (obj);
                callback(null, obj);
                return;
            }
        });
}
```

it is not working correctly.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: added my sample code and that is not working correctly

Comment: don't use return in filehandler.js because you always used callback method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when i passed the pptObj as obj and not as string.

```
pptObj = { "A":1, "B":2, "C":3 };
```

Solves the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var file = "./sample.txt";
var json = '{ "A":1, "B":2, "C":3 }';

fs.open(file, 'a', function(err, fd) {
    if (err) {
        try {
            throw new Error("Something wrong happend"); 
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("Error writing into file" + e);
        }
    }

    var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(json);

    for (var el in jsonParsed) {
        var buffer = new Buffer(el + " = " + jsonParsed[el] + '\n');
        var bufferLength = buffer.length;
        var bufferPosition = 0;
        var filePosition = null;

        fs.write(fd, buffer, bufferPosition, bufferLength, filePosition,
            function(err, written) {
                if(err) {
                    throw new Error(err);
                }

                console.log('Wrote ' + written + ' bytes');
        });
    }           

});
```

Please note that you need a valid json object, which means you need to put the json object between quotes.

Comment: `fs.exists()` shouldn't be used anymore:  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback